# Moq mocked DbContext returns null ObjectContext

Tags: c#, entity-framework, unit-testing, moq

I have a custom `DisconnectedDbContext` for use with self state tracking POCOs in a web app.

```
public abstract class DisconnectedDbContext : DbContext
{
    protected DisconnectedDbContext()
    {
        var objAdapterContext = ((IObjectContextAdapter)this).ObjectContext;
    }
}
```

I subclass this for some unit testing:

```
public class FruityContext : DisconnectedDbContext
{
    public virtual DbSet<FruitBowl> FruitBowls { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<Fruit> Fruits { get; set; }
}
```

And using `Moq` in a `TestMethod` as below:

```
[TestMethod]
public void CreateAFruityContext()
{
    var dbc = new FruityContext();
    Assert.IsNotNull(dbc);
    var mockSet = new Mock<DbSet<FruitBowl>>();
    var mockContext = new Mock<FruityContext>();
    mockContext.Setup(m => m.FruitBowls).Returns(mockSet.Object);
    var mo = mockContext.Object;
    Assert.IsNotNull(mo);
}
```

Now this is not an actual `TestMethod` so I don't want to get sidetracked about that.

My problem is that for the creation of `var dbc` in this method, `objAdapterContext` in the constructor call is not null however for `var mo` it is null. I need `objAdapterContext` to be not null, as per non-mocked objects because I tap into this to handle the `ObjectMaterialized` event of the `ObjectContext`.

So the Moq wrapper is changing the behaviour of my code. Is there something I can do about this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use this:

```
mockSet.CallBase = true;
mockContext.CallBase = true;
```